# biblatex publist (bibstyle=publist) get rid of numbering in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, macros, biblatex-publist

I would also like to get rid of the numbers in the bibliography and replace them by the command `\softbullet`. How can I do this?

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{soft}{rgb}{0.45,0.45,0.45}

% From .sty file:
\newcommand{\softbullet}{\textcolor{soft}{\small\textbullet}\hspace{0.5em}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\firstname}[1]{\def\@firstname{#1}}
\newcommand{\vonname}[1]{\def\@vonname{#1}}
\newcommand{\lastname}[1]{\def\@lastname{#1}}
\newcommand{\name}{\@firstname\ \@vonname \@lastname}
\makeatother

\RequirePackage[%
        backend=biber,
        bibstyle=publist,
        hyperref=auto
    ]{biblatex}

% Some code to get first name, middle name von-part and surname.
\makeatletter
\plauthorname[\@firstname][\@vonname]{\@lastname}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\bibsetup}{\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\makebox[\bibhang][l]{\softbullet}}
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{0.25\baselineskip}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{sample.bib}
@article{einstein,
    author = "Albert Einstein",
    title = "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
    [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
    journal = "Annalen der Physik",
    volume = "322",
    number = "10",
    pages = "891--921",
    year = "1905",
    DOI = "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004",
}

@book{dirac,
    title = {The Principles of Quantum Mechanics},
    author = {Paul Adrien Maurice Dirac},
    isbn = {9780198520115},
    series = {International series of monographs on physics},
    year = {1981},
    publisher = {Clarendon Press},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}

% This will be defined by users:
\firstname{Paul Adrien Maurice}
\lastname{Dirac}

\begin{document}

Hello, my name is \par
\name

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography


\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

I would like the gray dot to be about where the numbers are. If instead i use `style=authoryear,` and not `bibstyle=publist,` I get this:

[image]

Which is what I want, but with the `bibstyle=publist,` to be able to hide authors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a bibliography environment based on the definition of `itemize` in `article`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{soft}{rgb}{0.45,0.45,0.45}

% From .sty file:
\newcommand{\softbullet}{\textcolor{soft}{\small\textbullet}\hspace{0.5em}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\firstname}[1]{\def\@firstname{#1}}
\newcommand{\vonname}[1]{\def\@vonname{#1}}
\newcommand{\lastname}[1]{\def\@lastname{#1}}
\newcommand{\name}{\@firstname\ \@vonname \@lastname}
\makeatother

\RequirePackage[%
        backend=biber,
        bibstyle=publist,
        plnumbered=false,
    ]{biblatex}

% Some code to get first name, middle name von-part and surname.
\makeatletter
\plauthorname[\@firstname][\@vonname]{\@lastname}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\bibsetup}{\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{0.25\baselineskip}


\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\labelitemfont\softbullet}
     {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}%
      \def\makelabel##1{\hss\llap{##1}}}}%
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{einstein,
    author = "Albert Einstein",
    title = "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
    [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
    journal = "Annalen der Physik",
    volume = "322",
    number = "10",
    pages = "891--921",
    year = "1905",
    DOI = "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004",
}
@book{dirac,
    title = {The Principles of Quantum Mechanics},
    author = {Paul Adrien Maurice Dirac},
    isbn = {9780198520115},
    series = {International series of monographs on physics},
    year = {1981},
    publisher = {Clarendon Press},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

% This will be defined by users:
\firstname{Paul Adrien Maurice}
\vonname{}
\lastname{Dirac}

\begin{document}
Hello, my name is \par
\name

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Soft-bulleted list.]